# How to sum a number in sequence after click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var current =  0;
 current += 4;
 $('.add').click(function(){
  $('.box').html(current);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<div class="box">
 0
</div>
```

i want to sum a number in sequence after click the `add` button like the above snippet, so the results will be `4` `8` `12` `16` `18` and so on. Teach me how to do this ?

Comment: Move `current += 4;` inside click function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Your increment should be in the click function as well. SO the increment actually occurs when you click, if it's outside, it won't occur.

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            var current =  0;

            $('.add').click(function(){
                current += 4;
                $('.box').html(current);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to increment in click handler. Right now it is getting incremented only once.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var current =  0;
 
 $('.add').click(function(){
                current += 4;
  $('.box').html(current);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<div class="box">
 0
</div>
```

Comment: haha after a hours of searching the problem is only the variable location. Thank you sir @Suresh Atta

Comment: No problem. We all come through those situations :D happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the line `current += 4;` to inside the `click function` . so only you can `increment` the value `on click` .otherwise you will get `4` for every `click`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var current =  0;
 
 $('.add').click(function(){
                current += 4;
  $('.box').html(current);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<div class="box">
 0
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move count inside click function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 0;
  $('.add').click(function() {
    current += 4;
    $('.box').html(current);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<div class="box">
  0
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
The key is to grab the current value, add 4 to it and then replace that value with the new sum.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.add').click(function(){
      var existing = parseInt($("#result").text());
      
  $('.box').text(existing + 4);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<div id ="result" class="box">
 0
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Get the box value and next check value is numeric if true then add 4 and bind value in div.

```js
$('.add').click(function () {

    var current = $('.box').text();
    if ($.isNumeric(current))
        $('.box').html(parseInt(current)+4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<div id ="result" class="box">
 0
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move Current variable inside the click function..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var current =  0;

$('.add').click(function(){
   current += 4;
    $('.box').html(current);
});
});
</script>

<button class="add">add</button>
<div class="box">
0
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## working example

It is very simple, you just need to use loop and a array variable. set limit according to your requirement.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var current =  0;
var c=0;
var res = [];
$('.add').on('click', function(){
for (c = 0; c < 3; c=c+1){
current += 4;
res[c] = current
$('.box').html('&nbsp'+res);            
}
});
});
</script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<div class="box">   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```